# imperative logic on component that renders non-React components (mostly)

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component (let's call it `A`) that mainly renders a non-React component (a GIS map) and will on certain occasions display some modal dialogs. These dialogs are the only proper React components that the `A` component renders and are controlled by `A`'s local `State`. The GIS map draws some features (polygons) which the component receives through its `props`, but the logic to draw these features is purely imperative as the GIS map cannot be controlled by React.

So I have the following approach:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // check for changes between prevProps and this.props and
    // imperatively draw new polygons on map or remove polygons etc.
}
```

This works. However it occurred to me that when a new polygon arrives via `props`, the `render` is not necessary. This is because drawing the polygons on the map is done in an imperative way via direct DOM manipulation (through API calls to the GIS library). As such, I wrote a `shouldComponentUpdate` as follows:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   return !isEqual(nextState, this.state); // isEqual from lodash doing a deep comparison
}
```

The idea is that I only re-render my component for local state changes (which control a couple of modal dialogs) since these are the only React-controlled parts of the component and require `render` to be called. The rest of the changes (that affect non-React components) I pick up in `componentDidUpdate` and enforce imperatively (that was the plan at least).

The problem with the new approach is that if `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `false`, then `componentDidUpdate` is not called at all. So the only way to get hold of `props` changes that trigger imperative logic is via `componentWillReceiveProps` which is however **deprecated**.

Any thoughts? Is my approach flawed in a deeper level and/or how to deal with this connundrum? Is what I am trying to accomplish achievable only using a functional component approach (as has been suggested by a comment) and can I achieve it with class components as well?

Comment: How about re-writing your class component as a functional component and using the `useEffect` hook to track certain `props` changes? [Tip: Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Comment: With the class based approach you have `shouldComponentUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillReceiveProps` at your disposal. In the functional approach all those have been merged in one: the `useEffect` callback with its dependecies array. I think it actually allows for more flexibility. I don't fully grasp it, but my gut feeling is that you might not be able to do what you plan to do when you stick to the class based approach. Also I think the functional code is easier to reason about and therefore easier to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be an interesting problem. How are props mapped to your GIS-Widget?
React does allow nested elements that are not under *react rule* ([docu](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)).

I would ditch the old class based lifecycle functions and implement a functional component with `useEffect` and `useRef` hook.

Does the following code somehow resemble your current issue?
Let me know what I got wrong and we can make it work.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import gismap from 'gis-map';

const MyGISWrapper = ({ streets, waterways }) => {
  const map = useRef();

  // only once, on first render
  useEffect( () => { if (map.current) gismap('init', map.current); }, []);

  // update polygons when props change
  useEffect( () => {
    if (map.current) map.current.gismap('update', streets, waterways);
  }, [streets, waterways]);

  // some example modal
  const [showConfirmation, setShowConfirmation] = useState(false);
  const openConfirmation = () => setShowConfirmation(true);
  const closeConfirmation = () => setShowConfirmation(false);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="gis-map-root" ref={map} />
      <div className="modal-popup-area">
        { showConfirmation && <Confirmation onClose={closeConfirmation} /> }
      </div>
      <button onClick={openConfirmation} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Up-voted but I'm not sure how straightforward it would be to migrate my class component to a functional component given I use `State` a lot to control the display of modal dialogs etc. Is there no way to achieve the same thing in class components?